# quickblox android sdk unauthorized error

Tags: android, quickblox

I download the chat sample from quickblox and follow all the steps at http://quickblox.com/developers/5_Mins_Guide iam geting unauthorized error
i spending days for it for simple open groupchat feature in my app

please could some one help me.

```
splashActivity.java is

private static final String APP_ID = <my id>;
private static final String AUTH_KEY = <auth key>;
private static final String AUTH_SECRET = <secret key>;
//
private static final String USER_LOGIN = "vamsi";
private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "******";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the QuickBlox Admin Panel, go to the users section and add a new user with the credentials that you will be using first.